# Rails engine locale different from the main apps locale possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, activeadmin

My rails application has two sections. The main application and the admin interface. I want my main application to have Swedish as language and my admin interface to have English. The admin interface is implemented as a mountable engine, I'm using the activeadmin gem. Is it possible to define two different locals in the same application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up setting the default locale back to English and in a before filter in the main part of my application I set the locale to Swedish. This seems to work.